# Is there a way to impose current with an amplifier?

Tags: current, amplifier, feedback

I am trying to design a circuit to drive an inductor.  I need to set an output current flowing through the inductor, and I want to set it no matter the resistance on the output.

I found some current feedback amplifiers like the LT1795, but this is not as simple as I thought.

I'm thinking about adding a shunt on the output and inject that in a difference amplifier before the current amplifier, but is that a good way to do so?

Comment: e = L di/dt, you should estimate these parameters first depending on what you want. Cost tends to increase with voltage...

Answer (score 1):

> *I am trying to design a circuit to drive an inductor, and I need to
> set an out put current flowing through the inductor, and I want to set
> it no matter the resistance on the output.*

You cannot instantly force current into an inductor without infinite voltage. You can set the scene in terms of voltage so that the current in the inductor ramps towards the required value: -

$$\dfrac{di}{dt} = \dfrac{V}{L}$$

But, that's about all you can really do.

> *I'm thinking about adding a shunt on the output and inject that in a
> difference amplifier before the current amplifier, but is that a good
> way to do so ?*

That will produce a constant current output into a resistor but, for an inductor, the amplifier will end-stop against the power rails for a moment while the inductor plays catch-up as per the above formula. When the amplifier is railed all you can do is respect the more commonly seen version of the above formula: -

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer !
I am a little stubborn and I looked into current amplifiers, and I found a TI note (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa046/sboa046.pdf?ts=1617010072157) in which I found an intresting shematic in figure 52.

And then I found something on Howland's current pump, and I tried to mix a little bit that together.

I managed to make it work (in simulation) with an INA105 and a AD8016 used in follower. 
But I'm not actually sur to understand why it works, maybe it's because the load I am driving is small (10mH, 2Ohm).

Comment: @Justine you cannot make a current flow instantly in an inductor. That's all I'm saying. You cannot change the current flowing in an inductor instantly. If you are prepared to wait or drive it with a higher voltage then you can change the current more quickly. It's a law of physics and, irrespective of your driver (Howland current pump or the TI one), those circuits CANNOT change the current in an inductor instantly. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

I used a high-voltage, voltage-feedback opamp wired to drive power transistor to maintain a constant voltage across a current-sense resistor which led to an inductor. A high-voltage feedback opamp and a high voltage supply so it would have more voltage to drive fast current transients through the inductor. But that's hard on the MOSFET since it doensn't need that voltage most of the time except during hard transitions so it's burned off as heat. But this circuit died a lot from voltage spikes even with plenty of overvoltage protection because whenever the voltage was rapidly decreased the inductor would kick, hard.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUHVXj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I've been trying to simulate this since the question was posted, both with BJT and NMOS, but without **two** diodes back to back across the inductor it shows large oscillations. Which parasite capacitance causes this? It is worse with the mosfet.

Comment: You never specified what waveform you saw oscillations with so I can't comment further. If it was during decreasing current, that's inductive kick.

Comment: When I did it, I used MOSFETS because I was able to get linear MOSFETs in a massive SOT-227 package which I paralleled and bolted to a huge fanned heatsink. I was running a brutal sawtooth waveform. Not shown was bidirectional TVS diodes used for overvoltage similar to your back-to-back-diodes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm applying a pulse with slow slopes (~100ms) to the non-inverting input. I'll keep trying.

Comment: So a triangle wave? Where are the oscillations appearing? At the pointy peak? That's an abrupt change in slope as opposed to a gradual one like in a sine wave

Comment: This is getting interesting. It was similar to a trapezoid (100ms up, 100ms high, 100ms down), oscillations during the entire cycle. I changed to a 0.5Hz sine wave and there was no change at the oscillations, which happen during the whole cycle. Changing the NMOS changes the the amplitude and frequency of the oscillations. Is this worth a question?

Comment: @vangelo Yeah, probably. I never saw such oscillations when I built mine. Well, it was really tricky to tune it though. I remember that bit. But I don't recall what that bad behaviour was.